# No results found in custom lookup view in dynamics crm 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm, customization, lookup

I have written a custom lookup filter in CRM entity. When CRM language is english everything works fine. As soon as I change the language to Swedish, lookup filter do not show any results for initial characters.

What could be the problem?

```
fetchXml = "<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>"
                        + "<entity name='product'>"
                            + "<attribute name='name' />"
                            + "<attribute name='productid' />"
                            + "<attribute name='category' />"
                            + "<attribute name='externalid' />"
                            + "<order attribute='productnumber' descending='false' />"
                            + "<filter type='and'>"
                                + "<condition attribute='category' operator='in'>"
                                    + strValue
                                + "</condition>"
                                + "<condition attribute='type' operator='eq' value='1' />"
                            + "</filter>"
                        + "</entity>"
                    + "</fetch>";

        var layoutXml = "<grid name='resultset' object='1' jump='productid' select='1' icon='1' preview='1'>"
                                      + "<row name='result' id='productid'>"
                                          + "<cell name='name' width='300' />"
                                          + "<cell name='category' width='150' />"
                                          + "<cell name='productid' width='150' />"
                                      + "</row>"
                        + "</grid>";

        Xrm.Page.getControl("product").addCustomView(viewId, "product", viewDisplayName, fetchXml, layoutXml, true);
```

Comment: Did you remove the category condition with strvalue & test? This will isolate the rootcause.